# Istanbul Mocha and Sails using yeoman generator-sails-rest-api

Tags: sails.js, mocha.js, ecmascript-6, yeoman, istanbul

Im attempting to make this Code Coverage functionality work from the [Sails Documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/testing/code-coverage) so from the project root I run

```
istanbul cover -x "**/config/**" _mocha -- --timeout 5000
```

Which returns

```
Unable to resolve file [_mocha]
```

So thinking maybe because I am using this generator something is different so I try to use a path that is what is fired when doing 'npm test'

```
istanbul cover test/bootstrap.js _mocha -- --timeout 5000
```

and I get

```
No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information
…myprojectpath/test/bootstrap.js:1
import Sails from 'sails';
^^^^^^
```

I have little familiarity with Istanbul or mocha so I'm a little off in no man's land right now. For bonus points can someone tell me what the

```
-x
```

is doing?

*****EDIT*****

So using @MjZac suggestion below as the command line entry I was able to get it to work AFTER running

```
npm install -g mocha
```

However I notice my tests/generator might be more recent as it looks like ...

```
import Sails from 'sails';
import config from '../config/env/test';

let sails;

before(done => {

  Sails.lift(config, (error, server) => {
    if (error) return done(error);

    sails = server;
    done();
  });
});

after(done => sails.lower(done));
```

Which is now producing the exception

```
import Sails from 'sails';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Which I think is related to ES6 and istanbul?

Answer (score 0):

I use following command to make coverage in my sails projects.

`istanbul cover _mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/**/*.js && istanbul report html`

My project directory looks like

[image: Project directory]

My bootstrap.test.js
[image: bootstrap.test.js]

Comment: Your configuration looks identical to mine in fact the only difference is the file name ... mine is "test/bootstrap.js" - the bootstrap test file is also identical except that I put the 'timeout' into the mocha.opts file - I am still getting the message "Unable to resolve file [_mocha]"

Comment: do you have mocha installed?

Comment: So this is a little embarrassing but I just now realized this generator is configured to use babel-node and isparta for coverage I think specifically because of ES6 - so I did not know what isparta was after running the generator and overlooked it as I was just attempting to follow the sails docs - thanks for your help